# How to Redirect Facebook Request to iTunes?

Tags: ios, facebook, redirect, itunes

There are a few things i need to know, so please let me first explain my senario. In our iOS game what we need to do is when the user presses the Facebook button the game should open the Facebook and ask for login and then the user will authenticate the app. Rite after that the user will be shown his Friends from which he will pick up anyone he wants and sends the request (This is the only thing the game needs to do, our game will not receive any requests from Facebook). Now, the friend who gets the request when logs into Facebook (not from game, general login from safari or fb App for iOS) and clicks it, he will sent to the iTunes page to download our game.

Questions:

1) The App is not in the sandbox mode and there are only 2 admins and we are not getting each other requests. We are using Prime 31 social networking plugin which logins the and shows the friends correctly. 
So, looking at this conversation

[Linking Facebook app link to iTunes download page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298295/linking-facebook-app-link-to-itunes-download-page)

do I need to create a page for my app so that I could send requests and redirect the user to our iTunes game download page?

2) Is there any tutorial or guide lines available to do this or even possible? :(

Regards,
Abe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create facebook app and link dat app to your ios app as follows,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

After that try out the sample projects given with facebook sdk.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I have already created an app on Facebook. But there is one thing I dont understand. When the user will accept the app request, will he be automatically redirected to the Apple App Store due to the iPhone/ iPad App Store ID we have provided in Native iOS app setting? Rite now it shows page not found error. :(

Comment: Yp the iPhone/ iPad App Store ID we have provide will redirect you to the app. If the app is in your phone it will redirect to the app. In my case when i gave the store id it worked.

Comment: Thanks allot Kevin. You are a star.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering will we need to submit our Facebook App as well when we release our game on Apple App Store?